# Export Excel Selection (containing multiple graphs) to Outlook

Tags: excel, vba, image, graph, outlook

I am using the below code to export a certain Excel range to Outlook. It works really well and copies all the formats, etc. It even puts all the graphs in the right position, but unfortunately, none of the graphs are displayed properly:

[image: faulty images]

Is there anything that I could have missed (possibly disabled macros)? All the graphs are Column Charts, and I am using Office 2016 on Windows.

```
Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objMail = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)

With objMail
    .HTMLBody = fncRangeToHtml("Overview", "A5:W29")
    .Display
End With

'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

Private Function fncRangeToHtml( _
    strWorksheetName As String, _
    strRangeAddress As String) As String

    Dim objFilesytem As Object, objTextstream As Object, objShape As Shape
    Dim strFilename As String, strTempText As String
    Dim blnRangeContainsShapes As Boolean

    strFilename = Environ$("temp") & "\" & _
        Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy_h-mm-ss") & ".htm"
    Debug.Print strFilename

    ThisWorkbook.PublishObjects.Add( _
        SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
        fileName:=strFilename, _
        Sheet:=strWorksheetName, _
        Source:=strRangeAddress, _
        HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic).Publish True

    Set objFilesytem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objTextstream = objFilesytem.GetFile(strFilename).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    strTempText = objTextstream.ReadAll
    objTextstream.Close
    strTempText = Replace(strTempText, "align=center x:publishsource=", "align=left x:publishsource=")

    For Each objShape In Worksheets(strWorksheetName).Shapes
        If Not Intersect(objShape.TopLeftCell, Worksheets( _
            strWorksheetName).Range(strRangeAddress)) Is Nothing Then

            blnRangeContainsShapes = True
            Exit For

        End If
    Next

    If blnRangeContainsShapes Then _
        strTempText = fncConvertPictureToMail(strTempText, Worksheets(strWorksheetName))

    fncRangeToHtml = strTempText

    Set objTextstream = Nothing
    Set objFilesytem = Nothing

    Kill strFilename
End Function

Public Function fncConvertPictureToMail(strTempText As String, objWorksheet As Worksheet) As String
    Const HTM_START = "<link rel=File-List href="
    Const HTM_END = "/filelist.xml"

    Dim strTemp As String
    Dim lngPathLeft As Long

    lngPathLeft = InStr(1, strTempText, HTM_START)

    strTemp = Mid$(strTempText, lngPathLeft, InStr(lngPathLeft, strTempText, ">") - lngPathLeft)
    strTemp = Replace(strTemp, HTM_START & Chr$(34), "")
    strTemp = Replace(strTemp, HTM_END & Chr$(34), "")
    strTemp = strTemp & "/"

    strTempText = Replace(strTempText, strTemp, Environ$("temp") & "\" & strTemp)

    fncConvertPictureToMail = strTempText
End Function
```

Comment: Could you add `Debug.Print strTempText` before the end of the `fncRangeToHtml` function, rerun and paste what you get in the immediate window at the end of your question? It would be easier to solve the issue if the HTML that results from your code is available.

Comment: Can you share the spreadsheet?